# Restricción de input number con Jquery en cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova

Intento restringir el la coma de manera que en un `input` number, cuando le de no se escriba nada. Pero tengo la app con apache cordova, y coge todos los eventos de todos los números menos de los símbolos.

```
$(element).on('keypress', function(e) {
            var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode
                    if (e.which == 46)
                    {
                      e.preventDefault();
                    }
                  
        });
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona de las dos maneras. Sea con `preventDefault`, sea con `return false`:

```js
$("#ibxTest").keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.which;

  //Prohibiendo la coma
  if ((keyCode == 44)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }


  //Prohibiendo el  punto
  if ((keyCode == 46)) {
    return false;
  }

  console.log(keyCode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ibxTest" type="text" placeholder="No escribas ,">
```

### ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Según [esta respuesta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/5587982):

`return false` desde dentro de un controlador de eventos jQuery es efectivamente lo mismo que llamar a `e.preventDefault` y `e.stopPropagation` en el objeto `jQuery.Event` pasado en parámetro.

`e.preventDefault()` evitará que ocurra el evento por defecto, `e.stopPropagation()` evitará que el evento se borre y `return false` hará ambas cosas. Ten en cuenta que este comportamiento difiere de los controladores de eventos normales (no jQuery), en los que, en particular, `return false` no impide que el evento se borre.

Ver también: [Any benefit to using event.preventDefault() over "return false" to cancel out an href click?](https://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg71371.html)

Answer (score 4):

Es sencillo, simplemente pon `return false;` en lugar de `e.preventDefault()`.

Suerte.

Comment: La cuestion es que el keycode de los numeros si que los coge, pero el de los signos no. Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: @Ruben es como te ha dicho Jose FG, si no quieres que te escriba nada, añadelé un `return false` y otra cosa, el code 46 es el punto y no la coma, la coma es el **44**

Answer (score 2):

Bien, puedes impedirlo con **preventDefault()** si deseas continuar dentro de la función o del evento generado de la siguiente manera. la coma es el **44**

```
   $(".elemento").on('keypress', function(e) {
            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;                                 
                    if (code  == 44)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }

        });
```

O si prefieres que terminé en ese momento devolviendo un **return false** bastaría.

```
   $(".elemento").on('keypress', function(e) {
            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;                                 
                    if (code  == 44)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

        });
```